# Start WKExtendedRuntimeSession (WKExtendedRuntimeObject was dealloced while running)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos, wkextension

I have a problem when I try to start `WKExtendedRuntimeSession`

```
-[WKExtendedRuntimeSession dealloc]:285: WKExtendedRuntimeObject was dealloced while running. Invalidating the session 46EB2DE0-311C-41D0-93BE-46FE744B685A
```

```
class SessionCoordinator: NSObject, WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate {
    let runtimeSession = WKExtendedRuntimeSession();

    override init() {
        super.init()

        runtimeSession.delegate = self;
        runtimeSession.start();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue. Here is my solution.

1. Create a simple singleton class to manage WKExtendedRuntimeSession

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ExtendedRunTime: NSObject, WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate {
    
    static let shared = ExtendedRunTime()
    
    let session: WKExtendedRuntimeSession
    
    override init() {
        
        // Create the session object.
        session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
        
        super.init()

        // Assign the delegate.
        session.delegate = self
    }
    
    func extendedRuntimeSession(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession, didInvalidateWith reason: WKExtendedRuntimeSessionInvalidationReason, error: Error?) {
        print("didInvalidateWithReason: \(reason)")
    }
    
    func extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print("extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart")
    }
    
    func extendedRuntimeSessionWillExpire(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print("extendedRuntimeSessionWillExpire")
    }
    
    func start() {
        session.start()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        session.invalidate()
    }
}
```

2. Init the singleton. You can do this in .appear() or in your WKApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive()

`_ = ExtendedRunTime.shared`

3. Start the session where it is needed

`ExtendedRunTime.shared.start()`

4. Make sure to stop it when finished

`ExtendedRunTime.shared.stop()`

Answer (score 0):

I think, even if you design the App with a Singleton class to hold the WKExtendedRuntimeSession, the next time when you relaunch the App you will see the following error as Singleton may not be in the scope again.

```
-[WKExtendedRuntimeSession dealloc]:285: WKExtendedRuntimeObject was dealloced while scheduled. Invalidating the session 45E794AC-116A-4CD8-A027-DAF0FC7C4F1A
```

I think it's not a problem, it's simply invalidating the previous session and creating a new one.

But with in each App relaunch, after creating WKExtendedRuntimeSession you can check its been already scheduled or not as given below. Use **session.state** to check the current state.

```
    if (extendedSession == nil) {
        extendedSession = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    }
    
    if let session = extendedSession {
        // Return if already scheduled
        if (session.state == .scheduled) {
            Logger.shared.debug("ExtendedRuntimeSession: already scheduled..)")
            return
        }
        
        Logger.shared.debug("ExtendedRuntimeSession: start at : \(date.formatted())")
        session.delegate = self
        session.start(at: date)
    }
```

If you want to fix this problem completely, don't create WKExtendedRuntimeSession object again if its already scheduled in previous launch by storing that information in some FLAG. But I think creating WKExtendedRuntimeSession each time make sure it's invalidating old one and we can schedule the next. It's all depends on your logic.